# Please help me to understand the concept of inner and outer monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm not a monad-jedi yet, but I have a basic understanding of them.

Now I read some articles mentioning the 'inner' and 'outer' monad and I wonder what that means.

(Links to) code examples will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please link to those articles. Otherwise, your question is under-specified.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A lot of Haskell applications use monad transformers, which are instances of the type class

```
class MonadTrans t where
    lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

What this does is allow you do combine the environment provided by several monads, by wrapping them together.  For example, the `State s` monad gives you the ability to operate on state of type `s` that is automatically threaded through your computation, while the `Maybe` monad lets you short circuit failure.  But if you want *both* of those effects, then you can combine them by using a monad transformer version of one of the two, such as:

```
something :: StateT s Maybe a
```

Here, `StateT` is defined in the `mtl` package, and is similar to `State` except for leaving a place for another monad that sit inside of it.  By using monad transformers like this, you can compose the effects from several monads in a piecemeal fashion.

In this case, `Maybe` is the inner monad, and `StateT s Maybe` is the outer monad.  You can get from the inner monad to the outer monad by using `lift` from the `MonadTrans` type class.

Comment: You left out the state type parameter of `StateT`; it should be `something :: StateT Foo Maybe a` where `StateT Foo Maybe` is the outer monad.